# warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, compiler-warnings

I've looked though al the previous questions and answers on this error but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
@synthesize myScrollView;
@synthesize mathsPracticeTextArray;

-(void)loadText
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"mathspractice" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath];
    mathsPracticeTextArray = fileContents;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 960);
    myScrollView.pagingEnabled = FALSE;    
    myScrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
    myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    *[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,960,40)];
    myLabel.text = [mathsPracticeTextArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    [myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];*
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [myScrollView release]; 
    [mathsPracticeTextArray release];
    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

Comment: Can you put the log of the debugger please?

Comment: All I'm getting from the debugger is "session started" it actually compiles just fine with just a warning but its not showing my text from mathspractice.txt

Comment: Do I need a label in IB?

Comment: @Charles: how about telling us which line is causing the warning, and the declared type of all variables? Currently, the types of `myScrollView` and `mathsPracticeTextArray ` aren't specified.

Comment: @Charles Marsh: tags can not contain spaces, so write `objective-c` instead of `objective c`. This will ensure that many more people will see your question due to `objective-c` being in their interesting tags list.

Comment: UIScrollView *myScrollView; 
NSArray *mathsPracticeTextArray;

I'm sure the problem is with loadText

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `mathsPracticeTextArray` is declared as an `NSArray*` or `NSMutableArray*`, in which case assigning an `NSString*` to it (as happens in `-(void)loadText`) will cause the warning you mention in your title.

The warning is quite a clue what's happening: NSString is distinct from NSArray, and you can't treat one as the other. As you're assigning the wrong type of object to the variable, many messages you send to the object can't be handled and your app will fail.

Comment: like this?

-(void)loadText
{
 NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"mathspractice" ofType:@"txt"];
 NSArray *fileContents = [NSString     stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath];
 mathsPracticeTextArray = fileContents;
 
    }

Comment: Code never works well in comments; too messy. Changing the type of `fileContents` merely moves the problem to a different line, since it's now storing a string as an array. Look to the methods of `NSArray` (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).  Also, `stringWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithContentsOfFile_).